# Can we use a library under MIT license in a WooCommerce plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, licensing

I am in the process of developing a WooCommerce Plugin, and I plan to make two Free and premium versions. I want to join The `Bootsrap` library which is under the `MIT lisence`.
In the WordPress officle directory, I know that `MIT license` is fully GPL compatible. But, my question, can we sell a WooCommerce Plugin that uses 3th part under MIT lisence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, so this isn't legal advice.

Yes, you can include MIT licensed code in something you sell. The MIT license is very permissive. [From the license](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/):

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, **and/or sell** copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Also, in contrast to copyleft licenses such as [GPLv3](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/gpl-3.0/), the MIT license *does not* require that you relicense the rest of your product.

Comment: Hi thank you. should i mention the copyright in the description of the plugin?

Comment: You should definitely mention whatever copyright or license you're using. However, I don't think it would be necessary to mention the licenses of the third-party code in your plugin, as long as you retain their licenses in the code / filesystem.